# How do I uninstall/remove peewee?

Tags: python, macos, orm, peewee

I just know **peewee** and about to install it for some testings. And I want to know how to uninstall or remove it. I googled and searched in the docs, but couldn't find it. Please help me if you do know how. Thanks!

*P.S. I'm on OS X by the way.*

Comment: I don't know anything about OSX, but I suppose it depends on how you *install* it. If you use pip, `pip uninstall peewee`.

Comment: Yes, I will use `pip` to install. Oh! Is that it? Thanks @jedwards